# random error message popping up, I am very confused onto why this is happening?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
numbers = range(1,10)
for number in numbers:
    if number == 1:
        print(number + "st")
    elif number == 2:
        print(number + "nd")
    elif number == 3:
        print(number + "rd")
    elif number:
        print(number + "th")
```

There is an unexpected error that keeps on popping up. It keeps on saying "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". I tried changing some things but nothing seems to work!
If you can possibly help me, please give me an aswer. :)

Comment: Hint: think about what you are trying to add.  Are they similar objects?  Can they be added together?  For example: `print(str(1)+"str")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, strings can only be concatenated with other strings. You can't add a string and an integer. Instead, you would convert the integer to a string and then perform concatenation.

Like so:

```
print(str(number) + "st")
```